# Fragment Interface in fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I'm facing some problems in Android development. Environment is set to run in min API 23.

This is what I try to achieve :
I have a `MainActivity` with a `BottomNavigationView`. When an item in the `BottomNavigationView` is clicked it launches a Fragment. This works very well,I can send data to a fragment and have an interface to dialog with my activity.

The problem is :
On my Last fragment (`ProgramFragment`), I would like to make a Form Wizard. So, I would like to launch other fragments from the `ProgramFragment`. I used the same method I used in the `MainActivity` and I can launch the first fragment (`RecStartFragment`) where there is a button in the Layout. I want that when the button is clicked, the next fragment (`RecDataPatientFragment`) is shown. I get an error when I click on the button, saying that :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 
'void x.RecStartFragment$OnRecStartFragmentListener.startRecProg()' 
on a null object reference at 
x.RecStartFragment$1.onClick(RecStartFragment.java:30)
```

Is there a way to achieve that ? Why is that working from an activity but not from a fragment ?

Here is the code of the fragment `RecStartFragment`

```
package x;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class RecStartFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = RecStartFragment.class.getName();
    private View v;
    OnRecStartFragmentListener onRecStartFragmentListener;

    private Button btnStartRec;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(v != null) {
            return v;
        }
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rec_start, null);
        btnStartRec = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_rec);
        btnStartRec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onRecStartFragmentListener.startRecProg();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public interface OnRecStartFragmentListener
    {
        public void startRecProg();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            onRecStartFragmentListener = (OnRecStartFragmentListener) context;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Null Pointer Exception (NPE) indicating that the field `OnRecStartFragmentListener onRecStartFragmentListener` has not been initialised.

From your code, you are trying to initialise the field in `onAttach()` and catching exceptions, but not doing anything with them:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            onRecStartFragmentListener = (OnRecStartFragmentListener) context;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Try printing the stacktrace of any exceptions:

`e.printStackTrace()`

The context passed in `onAttach` is your `MainActivity` ? If so, is it implementing `OnRecStartFragmentListener` ?

Comment: I added the printStackTrace and get this message : `System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: x.MainActivity cannot be cast to x.RecStartFragment$OnRecStartFragmentListener
        at x.RecStartFragment.onAttach(RecStartFragment.java:45)`.

So I think that the error comes effectively from a problem of context passed.

But what can I do to pass the context of the fragment instead of the one if the Activity ?

Comment: @JulianHardenne That's the issue then. `ConnectActivity` needs to implement `RecStartFragment .OnRecStartFragmentListener `.

Comment: Oooh. So even if `RecStartFragment` is part of `ProgramFragment`, interface must be implemented by parent Activity and not by the parent fragment. When I write these lines, it seems logical because I remember to have seen in the Android Doc that you need to use an Activity to dialog between multiple Fragments.

Comment: @JulianHardenne Well as is often the case.....it depends. You are trying to cast from a `Context`. `Activity` is a `Context`, `Fragment` is not. However, if you started the fragment from a parent fragment, using a child fragment manager, then in `onAttach()` you would do something like `onRecStartFragmentListener = (OnRecStartFragmentListener) getParentFragment()` - assuming the parent fragment implements that interface.

Comment: Ok; so this solution solved my problem, I can now access the second fragment by implementing the interface on my parent activity ! Thank you very much for your help and your explanations !!!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the interface in your activity:

**Activity implementation:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecStartFragment.OnRecStartFragmentListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void startRecProg() {
        //Do whatever you need do here.
        Log.e("Calback:","Interface is working");
    }


}
```

Comment: This is the same solution than the one proposed by Veritas1 and it is working fine ! Thanks for your help guys !